# How to short (truncate) long products title in WooCommerce category pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to truncate long products title in shorter title with "..." at the end, in WooCommerce category page. If I'm right, products in category pages are displayed by a loop from "content-product.php".

The code is :

```
<li<?php echo $class ?>>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <div class="thumbnail">     
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>

        <?php if ( yiw_get_option( 'shop_show_name' ) ) : ?>
            <strong class="<?php echo $title_position; ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </strong>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>
</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
</li>
```

I found a lot of PHP functions to short a long string (this one seems simple http://shrtnr.us/r0yfwg), but I'm unable to apply the function to `the_title()`...

I'll appreciate if someone can put me on the right way. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution via jQuery, as suggested by Flobbo.

Firstly I changed : `<strong class="<?php echo $title_position; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></strong>`

to : `<span class="productname"><strong class="<?php echo $title_position; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></strong></span>`

And my jQuery code (placed before `</body>`is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.productname').each(function() {
        var title = $.trim($(this).text());
        var max = 31;

        if (title.length > max) {
            var shortText = jQuery.trim(title).substring(0, max).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
            $(this).html('<strong class="below-thumb">' + shortText + '</strong>');
        }
    });
});
```

Thats's all. It's a bit DIY but it works :)

**EDIT :**

The above jQuery function will truncate the string respecting words and spaces (to not cut a word). But if you don't care about words, you can modify the function like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.productname').each(function() {
        var title = $.trim($(this).text());
        var max = 30;

        if (title.length > max) {
            var shortText = jQuery.trim(title).substring(0, max - 3) + '...';
            $(this).html('<strong class="below-thumb">' + shortText + '</strong>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My content-product.php just shows `<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>`, any suggestions on how to modify your solution?

Comment: Nevermind. just added the productname class to my h3 title tag and changed span to h3 in the jquery code. Thanks!

Comment: @Miles, The jQuery code does all the work. So, yes you have just to replace the SPAN tag by your H3 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please use following code as per given here, it works fine - [shorten-woocommerce-product-titles](http://www.pixelninja.me/shorten-woocommerce-product-titles/)

Just put following code in your theme’s functions.php and its done.

```
    // Automatically shortens WooCommerce product titles on the main shop, category, and tag pages 
// to a specific number of words
function short_woocommerce_product_titles_words( $title, $id ) {
  if ( ( is_shop() || is_product_tag() || is_product_category() ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
    $title_words = explode(" ", $title);
    if ( count($title_words) > 5 ) { // Kicks in if the product title is longer than 5 words
      // Shortens the title to 5 words and adds ellipsis at the end
      return implode(" ", array_slice($title_words, 0, 5)) . '...';
    } else {
      return $title; // If the title isn't longer than 5 words, it will be returned in its full length without the ellipsis
    }
  } else {
    return $title;
  }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'short_woocommerce_product_titles_words', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

A very common issue: sometimes, WooCommerce product titles are way too long. On top of this, you may also want to keep the shop experience consistent and make all the WooCommerce product titles of the same length. This is how you do it.

You can use a simple CSS instead of long php code. this will 100% work on latest woocommerce.

```
  .shop-products.products .product .product-wrapper .product-name {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one because you have to figure out what is actually coming out of your the_title() function that you are calling. 
Best guess would be to do something like:
    $title = the_title(); 
Then check what's inside $title, if it's just plain text then you can use a truncate function like the one you mentioned. If it's more than plain text you have to filter out the actual part you want to truncate first.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried to catch the content of `the_title()` and to show via JS Alert, but it's empty outside the "strong" tags... :s Inside the "strong" tags the title is displayed correctly but some titles are too longs.

Comment: It's really hard to say what's coming out of the_title(). You could also theoretically use jQuery to truncate the contents in between the <strong> tags.

Comment: Ah thanks for the idea, I'll give a try to jQuery truncation.

Comment: It works :) Thanks Flobbo. You can give a look to my auto-answer. Best.

Answer (score 1):

```
function truncate($text, $limit) {
if (str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
    $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
    $pos = array_keys($words);
    $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
}
return $text;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
  $title = get_the_title();

  <?php echo truncate($title, <w/e number>); ?>
```

Throw the function into functions.php so you can use it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this purpose: [Woo Title Limit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-title-limit/)